# Computer Locked after period of time

Tags: windows-xp, screensaver

I have a Windows XP machine that locks itself after an unknown amount of time. I have disabled the screen saver completely, and unchecked "lock computer when coming out of standby". I've even overrode the settings with gpedit. Even still, it locks itself after a while, and it doesn't take long.

If it's any sort of hint, the time period for the screensaver is greyed out, even if I choose an actual screensaver.

Answer (score 2):

Is your computer a member of a domain (corprotae network)?  If so, that setting is usually controlled by domain policy.  See here for more info:

http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_stop_windows_xp_screensaver_asking_for_my_password.html